# Blocking a data stream until online

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have some buffered data in a Flowable that I send once the buffer fills up. **Unless** we're offline, in which case I want to block until we are back online.

The code I have without the offline bit is:

```
    dataSubject
        .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
        .compose(
            Transformers
                .buffer(
                    100,
                    5L,
                    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                    ScheduleProvider.computation
                )
        ) 
    .concatMapCompletable { dataSender.sendData(it) }
    .subscribe(/* deal with errors etc.. */)
```

I have another observable `networkConnectivity: Flowable<Connectivity>`
The part I can't figure out is how to use this to constrain the above code to send only when online.

Initially I tried `Flowables.combineLatest` but that is creating duplicate data being sent, since if we move offline and back online (but the data doesn't change) the same data is resent.

I also tried

```
networkConnectivity
    .flatMap {
        if (it.isConnected()) {
          dataSubject
            .toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
            .compose(
                Transformers
                    .buffer(
                        100,
                        5L,
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                        ScheduleProvider.computation
                    )
            ) 
        } else {
            Flowable.empty()
        }
    }
```

But the dataSubject isn't subscribed to until we're connected, and by then we've missed lots of data. Making the dataSubject a ReplaySubject doesn't seem like a good idea since it would re-send everything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If duplicated data is the only issue that you have with `Flowables.combineLatest`, then you can try to add `distinctUntilChanged` operator after `combineLatest`. It will filter duplicated data.
Here is the diagram how it works:
https://rxmarbles.com/#distinctUntilChanged

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I thought about it a bit, I think I still have the issue of if I'm offline and get multiple buffered items, I would only get latest.